# Noun phrase with multiple Complements

Tags: noun-phrases

Can Noun phrases have multiple complements?

Example:

> experiments that are feasible and that can also provide useful scientific observations for climate monitoring.

Would the entire sentence be a noun phrase?

Comment: Yes,but you do not have a complete sentence there: subject verb object.

Comment: And it doesn't have multiple 'complements': it has two modifying content clauses.

Comment: Anyway: feasible experiments that can also provide etc. is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *experiments* [*that are feasible*] *and* [*that can also provide useful*
>   *scientific observations for climate monitoring*].

It's not a sentence but, yes, it is a noun phrase.

The two bracketed elements form a coordination of relative clauses modifying the head noun "experiments".